# Change sitefeed webpart title

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, 2016

**Platform**: SharePoint 2016

I added a sitefeed webpart to a sharepoint page and it has a default title of **Newsfeed**.  I tried changing the title to something else but I get an error that says

***Unable to set property 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference***

TabHead1MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5 is the ID of my webpart.

Here's the code I have

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
alert("HELLO");
document.getElementById("TabHead1MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5").innerHTML = "Community";
})

function changeFeedBackTitle(){
    document.getElementById("TabHead1MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5").innerHTML = "Community News feed";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try below code in Script Editor web part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () { 
        document.getElementById("ms-currentFeedLabel").innerHTML="Community News feed"; }
</script>
```

However there is a click event associate to this link which will undo the changes again to Newsfeed.

Please refer Raghavendra Shanbhag's reply in this post:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/561fe1c1-c747-49b8-9145-de179259d615/change-title-of-newsfeed?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: that didn't work